# Spark shuffle data to less executors

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

I am running a complex logic in Spark, in order to get some metrics, I add `count` in someplace. [there are 2 stags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTe8D.jpg)

1. after reading data from S3, I got 22 tasks and data distributed on 22 executors[these tasks distributed on 22 executors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHp3Z.jpg)
2. I run `count`, the data shuffle to 4 executors with 200 tasks. [data shuffle to 4 executors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiy7a.jpg)

code:

```
    val newRdd = rdd.toDF()
      .repartition(Constants.cappingSparkPartitionNum, $"internal_id")
      .rdd // line 389
      .map(convertRowToConfiguration)

    Log.info(s"source, rdd.getNumPartitions: , ${rdd.getNumPartitions}, newRdd.getNumPartitions: ${newRdd.getNumPartitions}, count: ${newRdd.count()}") // line 392
```

Why did this happen?

How to control the data distributed on executors(40 executors) evenly?

Comment: `after reading data from S3, I got 22 tasks` - what Action did you execute exactly?

Comment: I performed an operation, after reading from S3, it is Dataframe, I transferred Dataframe to RDD, it is a stage.
Checked from Spark UI, there are 22 executors get involved.

Comment: Show code.......

Comment: You see 200 tasks because that's the default value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`

Comment: @shay__ I have no concern about 200 tasks, the question is why these tasks shuffle to 4 executors